# Global variable only returns value from the last instance in a loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, global-variables, leaflet

I've created a global variable outside of an ajax request; `var pos = [];` to collect latitude and longitude information of specific "jobs" coming from my api. "Jobs" also has it's own global variable outside the ajax request to collect an array of the data for each job (`var Jobs = [];`). Inside the ajax request, I have used the generic `Jobs = data` to set the variable value to the data being gathered in the request upon success (`success: function (data) {Jobs = data; ...`). I then use a `Jobs.forEach` loop to iterate through each Job. The `pos` variable is then given a value by using the `.getLatLng` Leaflet method on the marker created for each job. My problem is that when I try to call the `pos` variable (I'm testing using `console.log(pos);`) outside of the forEach loop, it only spit's back the last instance. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong? My simplified code is below. Note: I am trying to call `pos` inside another request, but it works fine for the global `Jobs` variable.

```
var grid = L.geoJson();
var Jobs = {};
var pos = [];

//var control = L.control.layers(grid).addTo(map);
// This is the ajax request for the jobs data
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  timeout: 8000,
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: Jobs,
  ...

  //Renders data to view
  success: function (data) {
    Jobs = data;
    Jobs.forEach(function (value) {
      console.log (pos);
      ...
      var latitude = value.latitude;
      var longitude = value.longitude;
      ...

      var marker = L.marker([value.latitude, value.longitude]).addTo(map);
      pos = marker.getLatLng();
      ...  
      console.log (pos);
    }); 

   // Fetch the file data making the grid       
    $.getJSON('./grid.geojson', function (data) {
       // Assign the results to the geojsonData variable

      console.log(Jobs);
      console.log(pos);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the `pos` variable each time with a new marker. 
`pos = marker.getLatLng();`

Instead you need to `.push` the new values into the array, this will add each new value in to the array

```
pos.push(marker.getLatLng()); //['marker1']
```

Then the next time the loop runs, the next marker will be added

```
pos.push(marker.getLatLng()); //['marker1', 'marker2']
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! I can then use it in `grid.getBounds().contains(pos)` to find out if the points are within the grid. I created another open variable with an array to store the results. Now I just need to figure out what to do with this info!

Comment: Great, glad it helped! :)